# Invoking one matlab script from another

Tags: matlab

How to a write a parent MATLAB program to take input from a file and pass it to another child MATLAB program and run it; after the child finishes executing, the control returns to the parent?

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you'd need to do that?

Comment: what is the problem with functions

Comment: I agree with Nishant. It seems to me that your "child script" should be a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a script from within a script. That is completely possible. Normally, if I have to give the child program an input, I would make the child program a function instead of a script, but since you want to have the child program as a script as well, you have to pass on the input from the file by making use of the workspace. Below are the steps:

1- Load the input from the file through the parent script and assign it a particular name. The input from the file should now appear in the workspace with that particular name.

2- The child script should be written as such that it refers to the input from the file with the same name that it appears in the workspace (the name that you assigned it).

That is it. Once the Child script runs it course , the control will automatically return to the parent script. The only thing you need to keep in mind is that a script will output all its variable to the workspace and it can sometimes get confusing.

Example:

```
% Parent Script
do stuff
Name = load(file);
ChildScript; % or whatever the child script is named.  
do more stuff
```

And

```
% Child script

for i = 1:numel(Name) 

   do even more stuff

end
```